# Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentTrasanction, java.lang.String)'

Tags: android, datepicker

Error is:

> Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentTrasanction, java.lang.String)'on line dialog.show(ft,"DatePicker");

Why am I getting this error? I have attached both the files required for this problem. help me to solve this error. Main class is given below:

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class OwnerInformation extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public EditText text_owner_name,text_owner_address;
public EditText text_owner_mob,text_owner_adhaar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner_information);

     text_owner_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.owner_name);
    text_owner_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.owner_address);
    text_owner_mob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
    text_owner_adhaar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adhaar_no);
    Spinner spinner_blood_group = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.blood_group);
    Spinner spinner_gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gender);

    ArrayAdapter adapter5 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(OwnerInformation.this,R.array.blood_group_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter adapter6 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(OwnerInformation.this,R.array.gender_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner_blood_group.setAdapter(adapter5);
    spinner_gender.setAdapter(adapter6);

    spinner_blood_group.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner_gender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    EditText datePicker2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);
    datePicker2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus){
            if(hasfocus){
                DateDialog2 dialog=new DateDialog2(view);
                FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");


            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String sSelected=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),sSelected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```

Date Dialog class is given below:-

```
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.DatePicker;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import java.util.Calendar;

 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
 public class DateDialog2 extends DialogFragment implements 
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
 EditText datePicker2;
 public DateDialog2(View view){
    datePicker2=(EditText)view;
}
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
 }

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    //show to the selected date in the text box
    String date2=day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
    datePicker2.setText(date2);
}
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `FragmentManager` to the `show()` method of DialogFragment, not the `FragmentTransaction`.

Replace

```
FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");
```

With

```
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
```

Comment: then what is the use of "ft"  @Max

Comment: please explain then what to write in show method because it is showing error on show method @Max